# Recursion in SQLite Database is locked

Tags: php, database, sqlite, recursion

I build something like tree using SQLite.
I use recursion in my task:

```
$this->recursion($row['id']...
```

My code works in old MySQL, but not in SQLite.

I get Fatal error: Database is locked in... line where I have INSERT. 
Because SELECT connection is using the database before INSERT.
And PHP insert only one records.

I used BeginTransaction and Commit, I used busyTimeout. It doesn't help me.

```
public function recursion($from, $to){
        $db = new SQLite3("db.sqlite");
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT value, s_id, sex FROM table WHERE id='. $from);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $row = $result->fetchArray();
//'database is locked' in next line
        $db->exec('INSERT INTO table (id, s_id, value) VALUES (null,'. $to . $row['value'] .'");');     

        if ($row['sex']=='fem'){
            $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id FROM table WHERE s_id=' . $from);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $result->fetchArray()){
                $this->recursion($row['id'], $db->lastInsertRowID());
            }
        }

}   




public function recursion($from, $to){      
        $res=mysql_connect($mysql_server,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass);
        mysql_select_db($mysql_db);

        $sql = 'SELECT value, s_id, s_id, sex FROM table WHERE id='. $from;
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $res);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (id, s_id, value) VALUES (null,'. $to . $row['value'] .'");', $res);     

        if ($row['sex']=='fem'){
            $sql = 'SELECT id FROM table WHERE s_id=' . $from;          
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $res);
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
                $this->recursion($row['id'], mysql_insert_id());
            }
        }
}
```

I repeat that my code works in MySQL.

Any idea? Any hint?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing connections INSIDE your recursive function. The first call will open/lock the database. The first recursive call will then try to re-open the database, and FAIL, because it was already opened in the parent context. MySQL code is only working because you're not recursing deep enough to hit its connection limit.

You should open the database ONCE, outside of your recursive function, then simply re-use that one handle at each recursion level. Same for MySQL.

There is very rarely EVER a reason to open multiple connections to a DB. About the only justifiable time is when you need to connect with different client credentials.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to take out db connection outside my function tomorrow in my work. I got reinsured.